# Excel UserForm data dump Into Access 2003

Tags: excel, ms-access

I am attempting to develop a user interface for people in my office that do not have ms-access on their PC.  I know it can be done with Excel and a UserForm but I am having trouble with the code.  I have a UserForms with TextBoxes for all relevant fields of data.  I have developed an Access database with corresponding fields.  My userform has command buttons to trigger the data transfer.  I am struggling with the language as I have never tried this before.  How is the language formatted for an Excel Userform text box to dump its data into an MS-database housed in the same folder?
Excel File is named TONUv2.xlsm, ms-Access database named TONU-9850.mdb

Comment: I'm confused by your question. What exactly are you trying to do? Move a userform from excel to Access?

Comment: Paolo, Im trying to use excel as an access interface for people who dont have access.